# What can I use instead of lcs (Longest common substring)

Tags: java, algorithm, lcs

I am trying to calculate the common string using lcs, but this algorithm only calculates 1 string. What can I use instead?

**LCS =** "*aaa*bbb*ccc*xxx" and "*aaa*ddd*ccc*" result: "aaa"

**but what i want=** "aaaccc"

help please:)

Comment: We can't help you if we don't see your code

Comment: but aaaccc is neither a substring of the first nor the second input.

Comment: do you want "*all* longest common substrings"? That would mean an output of `["aaa", "ccc"]`.

Comment: your requirement definition is ambiguous， and please provide what have you attempted

Comment: How many strings are you going to examine? In the example you gave there are two args. Also LCS is finding a substring rather than, Unions of substrings.

Comment: What is the expected result for, say, `AAAXBBBC` and `AAABBBC`?

Answer (score 1):

You can apply your LCS algorithm once to get the "aaa" result, then remove this result from both strings, and re-apply your LCS algorithm to get the "ccc" result. Finally you will concatenate the temporary results.

Your java code in the main class may look like the following (assuming that you have a method LCS(String string_1 ,String string_2) performing yourLCS algorithm:`

```
public static ArrayList<String> temp_results;
public static String string_1,string_2,temp_result,final_string;

public static void main(String args[]) {
    while (temp_result != null && !temp_result.equals("")) {
        temp_result = LCS(string_1,string_2);
        string_1.replaceAll(temp_result,"");
        string_2.replaceAll(temp_result,"");
        temp_results.add(temp_result);
    }
    for (String iterator_string : temp_results){
        final_string = final_string + iterator_string;
    }
    System.out.println("This is the result "+final_string);
}
public static String LCS(String string_1, String string_2){
    return ""; //put your actual LCS logic here, you should not return an empty string!
}
```

Comment: LCS Algorithm works with a single String at a time, so what if the `LCS` method find two different substrings in the given Strings? Consider the example of *'aaaabbb'* and *'aazbbb'* -> desired output should be *aabbb*

Comment: @dbl no, that should not be the output, the output should be `bbb`, that is the only LCS.

Comment: @luk2302 unfortunately you are not correct. The OP asks for an algorithm that finds a string constructed of the common chars between the two strings. The misused "LCS" in the title is misleading OK - still the desired output should contain all the common chars according to the expected output. Since the specification is unclear -> question is put on hold. Cheers.